# immutable.js does not export Map

Tags: angular, ionic2, immutable.js, rollupjs

I recently update my Ionic2 project from `2.0.0-beta.11` to `2.0.0-rc.0`. I'm using Immutable.js (version ^3.8.1). Since the update I encountered the following error during Ionic Serve command:

```
[16:50:23] bundle dev started ...
[16:50:40] Error: Module /myproject/node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js does not export Map (imported by /myproject/.tmp/effects/catalog.effects.js)
at Module.trace (/myproject/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:7677:29)
at ModuleScope.findDeclaration (/myproject/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:7300:22)
at Scope.findDeclaration (/myproject/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5351:39)
at Scope.findDeclaration (/myproject/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5351:39)
at Scope.findDeclaration (/myproject/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5351:39)
at Scope.findDeclaration (/myproject/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5351:39)
at CallExpression.bind (/myproject/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5826:28)
at /myproject/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5151:50
at ReturnStatement.eachChild (/myproject/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5168:5)
at ReturnStatement.bind (/myproject/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5151:7)
```

I don't know if I need to add some inclusion into my app.module.ts file. I probably miss something.

Thanks.

Comment: See [https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/68](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/68)

Comment: It seems that was the problem. Thw !!!

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about your project and setup it's hard to know exactly what the problem and solution are, the error message...

> Error: Module /myproject/node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js does not export Map

...gives us a clue. [That file](https://unpkg.com/immutable@3.8.1/dist/immutable.js) is a UMD module, and by default Rollup only understands JavaScript modules (with `import`/`export` declarations). We can convert it using [rollup-plugin-commonjs](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs), but in this case there's an extra step required because there's no way for Rollup to know that Immutable has an export named `Map` without actually running the code. (In some cases it'll figure it out – when a module has e.g. `exports.foo = bar` it'll add a named `foo` export, but Immutable does things differently.)

So we help it by using the `namedExports` option in rollup-plugin-commonjs:

```
plugins: [
  commonjs({
    include: 'node_modules/**',
    namedExports: {
      'node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js': [ 'Map', 'Set', ... ]
    }
  }),
  ...
]
```

This is unfortunate but necessary, because the semantics of CommonJS modules are fundamentally different to ES modules.

Comment: That for this first answer and sorry if my question was not detailed enough. To be clearer, I'm currently developing a Ionic2 / Angular2  / RxJS / Immutable.js phone app. I'm including Immutable into my js file using the following syntax `import {Map} from 'immutable';`. Before upgrade Ionic for beta.11 to rc.0, this inclusion worked fine. But since the upgrade import  failed in one file, not in all files (works in `NgModule` file) . And Ionic use `rollup`, `rollup-plugin-commonjs`, `rollup-plugin-node-resolve` and `rollup-pluginutils`. I hope it could help

Answer (score 1):

That was a [core issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/68) who required [an update](https://twitter.com/Justinwillis96/status/783033856194547712).